# Array as parameter in Doctrine SQLFilter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to create Doctrine SQLFilter. I need to filter for "deleted" field. But i want to make filter works with both (true and false) values too.

Something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Rem\CostsBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

class ItemDeletedFilter extends SQLFilter
{

    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        if ($targetEntity->getReflectionClass()->name != 'Rem\CostsBundle\Entity\Item') {
            return '';
        }

        $fdata = $this->getParameter('deleted');

        $filter = '1<>1';
        foreach ($fdata as $param) {
            $filter .= sprintf('OR %s.deleted = %s', $targetTableAlias, $param);
       }

        return $filter;
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to set array of posible filter values in controller

```
$filters
    ->enable('costs_item_deleted')
    ->setParameter('deleted', [true, false]);
```

I get an error 500

```
Warning: PDO::quote() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

This is clear situation. But, after all HOW to send array of params to my SQL filter?

**UPD after Dmitry answer**: This is not actualy what I wanted. Let say: what if I wanted to filter by few values of field? For records of 2015 and 2016 years for example... So i need to set some sort of array-of-years in ->setParameter. But it want only strings! And sends an error when i'm trying to set something else.
How do you solve this?

Or even more complicated example. What if I need to filter by relational field. In this case I need to set entity as param of filter. Or even ArrayCollection of entities!

For now I'm decide it like this: I json_encode array before set it to setParameter in controller. And then I json_decode it in Filter class. BUT! There in Filter class I need to make one more step. I need to remove single and doublequotes from json string. Because they was added by setParameter to escape string (thats why we love it )) ).

Code hacks like this we call "crutches" here in Russia. So I'd like to avoid of them and write more elegant code )

Comment: Or maybe there is another way to apply one filter to query many times with different parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Make it **IN** instead of comparing.

```
foreach ($fdata as $param) {
    $filter .= sprintf('OR %s.deleted IN (%s)', $targetTableAlias, param);
}
```

Comment: You will still have the `PDO::quote()` error. The first issue is to be able to get an array parameter, which does not seem to be supported yet